# Parse Push Notifications - Swift Installation Not Working

Tags: swift, notifications, parse-platform, push

I am trying to get Parse push notifications working on my app (all swift) but while trying to implement, I get the error `'PFInstallation' does not have a member named 'saveInBackground'`

Here is my code.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    Parse.setApplicationId("APP ID HIDDEN", clientKey: "CLIENT ID HIDDEN")

   // let notificationTypes:UIUserNotificationType = UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound
    //let notificationSettings:UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: notificationTypes, categories: nil)
    var notificationType: UIUserNotificationType = UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound

    var settings: UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: notificationType, categories: nil)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()

    //UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return true
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterUserNotificationSettings notificationSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings!) {
   UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()

}

func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {

    var currentInstallation: PFInstallation = PFInstallation()
    currentInstallation.setDeviceTokenFromData(deviceToken)
    currentInstallation.saveInBackground()

    println("got device id! \(deviceToken)")

}


func application(application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError) {
    println(error.localizedDescription)
    println("could not register: \(error)")
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    PFPush.handlePush(userInfo)
}
```

When I change the `currentInstallation.saveInBackground` to `currentInstallation.saveEvenutally()` , the code compiles fine..

But when trying to successfully sign up for push notifications, an error pops up in the console saying `Error: deviceType must be specified in this operation (Code: 135, Version: 1.4.2)`

I have spent hours trying to figure this out, no dice, any help is appreciate.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To anyone else who has this error, make sure you import the Bolts framework into your Bridging Header file

Which isn't outlined in their crap docs.

That fixes the issue.

Below is the code.

```
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import <Bolts/Bolts.h>
```

Just add that to your bridging  header then you are good to go. Thanks

Comment: This still doesnt fix it for me :(, doing this + var currentInstallation: PFInstallation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation() worked

Comment: `import Bolts`
That's it

Answer (score 7):

> A valid PFInstallation can only be instantiated via [PFInstallation currentInstallation] because the required identifier fields are readonly. ([source](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFInstallation.html))

So instead of:

```
var currentInstallation: PFInstallation = PFInstallation()
```

Try:

```
var currentInstallation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
```

Comment: Ok, that didn't do much. Still has the error "'PFInstallation' does not have a member named 'saveInBackground'"

Comment: It gets the deviceID fine, just won't register on Parse's side as an installation. It won't receive push's

Comment: Well you won't receive pushes until you get the save method to work. Is `currentInstallation` maybe an optional for some reason? Option-click it and see if it's of type `PFInstallation?`

Comment: I don't see anything about it being optional.

Comment: I'm not sure what to tell you then! You're sure `saveInBackground` exists in the version of Parse you're on, and your object isn't an optional (`PFInstallation!` or `PFInstallation?`)?  [Here](https://github.com/aclissold/The-Oakland-Post/blob/fe578efd6b7d6f25d1ac336d6a9d7d6e32906e13/The%20Oakland%20Post/AppDelegate.swift#L55,L58)'s a working implementation…

Comment: Well, it's whatever the newest version of Parse is. I just downloaded it today.

Answer (score 4):

Just write `import Bolts` in you AppDelegate.swift file

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The current accepted answer doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to importing Bolts, I fixed the same error in my app by changing the function to

```
 func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
    // Store the deviceToken in the current Installation and save it to Parse
    let installation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
    installation.setDeviceTokenFromData(deviceToken)
    installation.saveInBackground()
}
```

From the Parse guide on Push Notifications (as opposed to quickstart guide): https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#push-notifications